# Adding BarButtonItem To NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I Added a NavigationBar Through IB and I Tried to Add a BarButtonItem Programatically.....But it Doesn't Work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(EditTable:)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:self.addButton];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Did you see the navigationbar without any button?

Comment: Did you get this fixed Chandu?

Comment: yes @chown i got it fixed. but in a different way

Answer (score 4):

Try to do this :

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped:)];
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case try this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(EditTable:)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
```

I guess this might work.

Comment: I think it works with the navigation bar added programatically...But i added it from IB

Comment: If you've added a BarButtonItem from IB then you don't need to write this code at all. Just define an Outlet for the bar button item, drop it on the navigation bar and connect its method like we do in case of UIButtons.

Comment: ...yes i did it...but i wanna add an 'edit" button as right bar button which changes to 'done' when clicked.

Comment: In that case, add a checking flag in the `EditTable:` method if the title of the BarButtonItem is 'Edit' change it to 'Done' like this `[editButton setTitle:@"Done"];` and keep toggling when the user clicks that button. Also change the style to done by this `[editButton setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];` when title is 'Done', if you wish to make it blue.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is right, but so far, you've only added the addButton to a UINavigationItem as the leftBarButtonItem. To add it to a navigationBar, you need to then push the navigationItem onto it, similar to how you add a new UIViewController to a UINavigationController. Assuming you name your UINavigationBar navBar:

```
UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];

self.addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(EditTable:)];
[navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:self.addButton];

[self.navBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];
[navigationItem release];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: All the other methods noted work if you are using a UINavigationController, as it will handle its UINavigationBar's navigationItem pushing/popping internally. If you use a UINavigationBar without the controller, you must do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init]; 
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(EditTable:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButton;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
```

Comment: No Sir, Didnt get it Yet..I added this bar in a modalView.(if it makes any difference from a normal One.)

Answer (score 0):

For some views the leftBarButtonItem doesnt work and you need to use the backBarButtonItem.  Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
    [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(EditTable:)] autorelease];
    // Or, if that doesnt work for some reason use:
    // [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(EditTable:)] autorelease];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Also, your creating a variable within the scope of `viewDidLoad` called `addButton`, but then you are trying to set the property `self.addButton` as the `leftBarButtonItem`.

Either remove the `self.` from the `self.addButton` in:

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:self.addButton];
```

or initialize the property instead of creating a new item with the same name:

```
self.addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(EditTable:)];
// instead of:
// UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(EditTable:)];
```